# Python: Loop through a folder and save data from first tab of each file and save to new file on separate tabs

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to loop through 8 files in a specific folder and grab the data from specific column in the first tab of each. Then, I want to paste the data into a new, consolidated file with each of the data frames on their own separate tab. This is what I have so far...

My questions:

1. How do I grab the data from the first tab of each file?
2. How do I then paste that data into each of their own tabs on a consolidated file?

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob



os.chdir(file path)
FileList = glob.glob('*.xlsx')

data = {}

for file in FileList:
   df = pd.read_excel(file, 0, header=9)
   df = df[['Project Code', 'Project', 'Location', 'Opening Balance Dollars', 'Accrued This Year Dollars',
            'Opening Balance + Accrued Dollars', 'Taken Dollars', 'Closing Dollars']]
   data[file] = df
```

Comment: you have not added the question - what exactly is not working, what is expected behaviour and what is actual outcome?

Comment: The only thing not working so far is the read_excel for each of the first tabs. Not exactly sure how to look at only the first tab of each file. 

Also, not sure where to start on pasting the data from each file in to a new tab on consolidated file.

Comment: As stated before, please edit your post so that It actually includes a question. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) helps as well.

Answer (score 0):

To save to excel you need to have **openpyxl** installed. Then I would append each df to a list:

```
  Filelist = glob.glob(r"path\*.xlsx")

  list_df = []
  for file in Filelist:
      list_df.append(pd.read_excel(file))

  # the names for each sheet in the consolidated file
  names = ['sh1','sh2']

  writer=pd.ExcelWriter(r"path\out.xlsx")
  for i, df in enumerate(list_df):
        df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="{0}".format(names[i]),index = False)

  writer.save()
```